# How to check the remote incoming changes from Version Control System (git) in WebStorm Editor?

Tags: eclipse, git, webstorm

Basically looking for the **Eclipse** like **Synchronize View** option in WebStorm. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet available, as the "[Repository and Incoming Tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/repository-and-incoming-tabs.html)" mentions:

> The Repository and Incoming tabs are only available for non-distributed version control systems (i.e. all VCSs supported by WebStorm except for Git and Mercurial).

You would need to do a [fetch through the GUI](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/fetching-changes-from-a-remote-git-repository.html), and then [compare branches](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html#d572242e308).

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/git_branch_checkout.png]

(Or checking the [Log View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/log-tab.html))